# TFS - How to set build definition to build on workspace changes, but NOT download files to workspace?

Tags: tfs, build, tfsbuild

I have our Solution on CI build.  That works.

When dev's check in changes, the solution builds, but only for changes to that solution.

How do I get the build definition to build on changes to OTHER folder changes outside of the solution?

Yes, I can add a workspace in the workspace sources tab.  But that means all that code is downloaded on every build.

Our solution has over a dozen dependencies.  I would like to trigger a build if any of those dependencies change.  We don't need the dependency source code to download into the build workspace at all.  That's just pointless.

Yes, we have a folder in TFS for our Nuget Packages.  We check them in automatically on build (Thank you TFS).

I could just add the NugetPackage workspace to the solution's workspace list, BUT that would result in every version of every dependency getting downloaded into the build workspace.

How can I trigger a build on a change that I do NOT list in the workspaces list of the build definition?

Btw, we are using TFS 2012

I was hoping the Cloaking feature would allow for this, but if it's cloaked, the automated build does not trigger.  The automated build only fires if the workspace folder is set to active.  Which also means download every NugetPackage in that same folder!

Answer (score 1):

It's not able to trigger a CI build on a change which not list in the workspaces list of the build definition.

> **A few other things to know**
>
> - Make sure the folders you include in your trigger are **also included    in your mappings on the Repository tab**(the same to
>     workspace mappings).
>
> [Source Link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/triggers)

As a workaround you could set [clean workspace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647547(v=vs.120).aspx#Get%20your%20code) to **false**,  which will not get other unchanged files every time.

> If your build process does not require a clean workspace or
>   repository, you can significantly reduce the time that is required to
>   run the build setting this parameter value to False.

Comment: Even Team Foundation Server 2017 hasn't resolved this yet?  Wow

Comment: Unfortunately management insists on a clean workspace yes.  It makes no sense to me why Microsoft would marge these two discrete pieces of information.  The need to monitor a folder for change is independent of the need to get the latest files from that folder during build.  I really hope MS splits up these two pieces of information at some point.  There is a need for both cases independent of the other.  There are a lot of people using a third party tool to get version control files onto their build server during build outside of the monitoring scope as well.

Comment: @user5855178 I would like to know, how to build the project/solution if the dependences' source code isn't getting download to the agent work space? You can provide the samples to explain it.